# Duda problema funciones

Tags: python

soy nuevo en programación y llevo varios días intentando resolver la siguiente tarea sin llegar a ningun resultado.

"Calcular una función que calcule si un string dado es una dirección de email válida o no. Para ello debe contener @ y acabar en ".com". Si es valido devolverá True y sino False."

He intentado varios códigos y no consigo que me funcione, agradeceria si alguien pudiese ayudarme. Me han dicho que se podría hacer con expresión regular, el problema es que no se como hacerlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo!

Uno de los codigos que he estado usando es el siguiente, pero me da error:

```
def validar(email):
caracter= "@" and ".com"
if caracter in email:
    return True
else:
    return False

direccion=input("")
if validar(direccion):
print("valido")
else:
print("invalido")
```

Comment: Bienvendx bnmart c: Te recomiendo que le heches una leida a estos dos links: https://j2logo.com/python/tutorial/tipo-str-python/#str-in y http://www.w3big.com/es/python/att-string-endswith.html. Estos links tienen información sobre como podrías avanzar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este codigo no funciona porque esta mal identado no? aparte de eso, que trataste de hacer con esto? caracter= "@" and ".com" sabes que una variable puede contener un solo valor, no?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que la sintaxis Python está haciendo lo que tú le pides, y no lo que tú querrías :-)

Me explico, ¿qué pretendes que haga esta línea?

```
caracter= "@" and ".com"
```

Porque lo que está realmente haciendo es la operación lógica entre `"@"` y `".com"` (sale `True`, luego explico por qué) y almacenando el resultado en la variable `caracter`.

Por tanto `caracter` vale `True`, por lo que cuando luego haces:

```
if caracter in email:
```

realmente estás buscando `if True in email`. Y no va a estar, porque `email` es una cadena de texto y no una lista de booleanos. De modo que esa condición **nunca se cumplirá**.

### ¿Por qué `"@" and ".com"` sale `True`?

Porque `and` es un operador booleano que opera entre datos de tipo de booleano para producir otro booleano. Los datos con que ahora está intentando operar es `"@"` y `".com"`, que no son booleanos sino strings, de modo que Python implícitamente los convertirá en booleanos para poder hacer la operación. Lo que hace por tanto es:

```
bool("@") and bool(".com")
```

La conversión a booleano de un dato sigue unas reglas bastante sencillas. Si el dato es un numero, se converierte en `False` si vale cero, o `True` en cualquier otro caso. Si es una cadena, una lista o un diccionario, se convierte a `False` si la cadena, lista o diccionario están vacías, o a `True` en cualquier otro caso.

En este caso particular las cadenas `"@"` y `".com"` no están vacías, por lo que ambas resultarán en `True`, de modo que la operación `and` dará también como resultado `True`.

### ¿Qué pretendías?

Seguramente mirar si se cumplen a la vez dos condiciones:

- `"@"` está en el email
- Y `".com"` también está en el email

Por tanto tienes que hacer ambas comprobaciones y unir con un `and` el resultado de cada una. Es decir:

```
def validar(email):
  if "@" in email and ".com" in email:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Y este código aún puede abreviarse más ya que básicamente le estás diciendo: "si el resultado de esta expresión booleana es True retorna True, y si es False retorna False". ¿Ves la redundancia? Podrías simplemente decirle "retorna el resultado de esta expresión booleana".

Por tanto:

```
def validar(email):
  return "@" in email and ".com" in email
```

Aunque realmente esto no cumple del todo las especificaciones del enunciado, ya que te piden que contenga `"@"` (lo cual se está mirando bien con `in`) pero *que termine* en `.com` (lo cual no se está mirando bien con `in` ya que el `.com` podría estar por el medio y seguiría dándose por válido). Para verificar que está realmente al final hay que usar el método `.endswith()` de las cadenas. Así:

```
def validar(email):
  return "@" in email and email.endswith(".com")
```

Comment: Una duda, porque soy muy novato en Python. ¿Serviría `return "@" in email and email[-4:] == ".com"`?

Comment: si, tambien sirve